# How to link an icon to a Rust Windows application?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, rust-cargo

In a Rust desktop application, some version of the window `struct` is always used, e.g., `WNDCLASSW`. When `WNDCLASSW` is defined, a *class icon* may be added through the `struct` member `hIcon`. The code excerpt below demonstrates how to include the icon stored in the file `Icon.ico`.

```
...
        let hicon: HICON = LoadImageW(
            0 as HINSTANCE, 
            wide_null("Icon.ico").as_ptr(), 
            IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE
        ) as HICON;

        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

        let mut wc: WNDCLASSW = std::mem::zeroed();
        wc.lpfnWndProc = Some(window_proc);
        wc. hInstance = hinstance;
        wc.hIcon = hicon;
        wc.lpszClassName = name.as_ptr();
...
```

The icon file is loaded during the program execution and must be stored in the same folder as the `exe` file. If the icon file is missing, `LoadImageW()` returns a `NULL` handle. Setting `hIcon` to `NULL` is valid and causes the use of a standard system icon.

While this approach produces the required icon, the icon file is loaded during execution and must be delivered along with the `exe` file. This isn't an acceptable solution; the icon should be linked to the `exe` file and delivered within it.

How do I link an icon to a Rust Windows application and use it there?

I am aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291757/attaching-an-icon-resource-to-a-rust-application), but it generates thousands of lines of errors and warnings during compilation and must be seen as outdated. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839529/changing-the-icon-of-an-exe-file-in-rust) works, but it only adds the *exe icon* shown in Windows `File Explorer`, while the *class icon* (in the taskbar) is unchanged. Several other solutions for the *exe icon* may be found on the internet, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use the [embed-resource](https://crates.io/crates/embed-resource) crate to compile your .rc file(s) and have them linked into the binary.

Comment: @IInspectable: I'll experiment with this, but it opens new questions. I don't use any .rc file and don't know what it should contain. And if I succeed in linking the icon, how do I use it? You cannot use ``LoadImageW()`` any longer, so you have to set ``hIcon`` in some other way. A relevant example would help a lot.

Comment: Your .rc file would need to contain an [ICON resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/icon-resource) definition statement for each icon you want to have embedded. It doesn't have to contain anything else. [`LoadImageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew) can be used to load icon resources. You just need to construct a `PCWSTR` that holds the ID rather than a pointer, e.g. `PCWSTR(42 as _)` for a resource with ID 42.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you; I'll give it a try. But if you know how to solve it, why don't you add all the details and make it the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard procedure to embed resources into an executable image on Windows is to author a [resource file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files) (.rc), have the [resource compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-rc-the-rc-command-line-) translate that into its binary representation, and pass that to the linker.

Since it's somewhat tedious to interact with the linker from Cargo, it's a fair bit easier to use an existing crate to deal with this. As you've discovered, there's [winres](https://crates.io/crates/winres) (which appears to be a bit outdated), so I'll be using [embed-resource](https://crates.io/crates/embed-resource) here.

If you want to play along, start by creating a new binary crate

```
cargo new --bin embed_icon
```

Next, copy an icon of your choosing into the crate's root directory (I'm using "rust_lang_logo.ico" downloaded from [here](https://icon-icons.com/icon/rust-lang-logo/169776)) and create the resource script (embed_icon.rc) in the same location:

```
1 ICON "rust_lang_logo.ico"
```

All this does is tell the resource compiler that it should look for an icon called `"rust_lang_logo.ico"`, and assign it an ID of 1 when producing its binary output.

Of course we need a Cargo.toml as well:

```ini
[package]
name = "embed_icon"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.43.0"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
    "Win32_System_LibraryLoader",
]

[build-dependencies]
embed-resource = "1.8"
```

This is declaring the required `windows` features we'll be using, and imports embed-resource as a *build* dependency. What's left is src/main.rs

```rust
use windows::{
    core::{Result, PCWSTR},
    Win32::{
        System::LibraryLoader::GetModuleHandleW,
        UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{LoadImageW, IMAGE_ICON, LR_DEFAULTSIZE},
    },
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let _icon = unsafe {
        LoadImageW(
            GetModuleHandleW(None)?,
            PCWSTR(1 as _), // Value must match the `nameID` in the .rc script
            IMAGE_ICON,
            0,
            0,
            LR_DEFAULTSIZE,
        )
    }?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This doesn't do much, other than trying to load the icon we just embedded into the binary. A `cargo run` later, and we have...

> Error: Error { code: HRESULT(0x80070714), message: "The specified image file did not contain a resource section." }

and a binary that looks like this in File Explorer:

[image: Screenshot with no embedded resource]

The final step is to actually run embed-resource and have the icon linked into the executable image. A [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) is required to do this. To add one create a file called "build.rs" in the crate's root directory with the following contents:

```rust
fn main() {
    embed_resource::compile("embed_icon.rc");
}
```

This neatly brings it all together. Running the executable is now successful, and the binary has a nice icon associated with it when displayed in File Explorer:

[image: Screenshot with embedded resource]

---

*Note:* The solution above uses the [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate, which is designed for convenience and better safety. If you are using the [winapi](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) or [windows-sys](https://crates.io/crates/windows-sys) crate the core principles are still the same. The code in main.rs would have to be adjusted, though.

Comment: Adding an *exe icon* is known, e.g. see the link in my question. I want to add a *class icon*. Your answer is knowledgeable but it doesn't solve the problem, it **does not produce the correct icon in the taskbar**. I'm trying to use your comment to set ``hIcon`` in ``WNDCLASSW``.

Comment: @KalleSvensson That appears to be a different issue then (could be, that the .ico you are using doesn't contain an icon image for the required resolution). I updated my test code with a call to `MessageBox` and the icon shows up properly in the taskbar button as well. Regardless, this proposed answer addresses an issue with the `winres`-based solution: It puts you in control of assigning an ID to the icon resource, making it possible to refer to it in code. `winres` (from a quick look) doesn't provide a way to do that. Though I could be wrong.

Comment: The icon I'm using is good; it does pop up in the taskbar when I load it from a separate file, as shown in the question. Your test app just flashes and disappears, so I added a sleep after the call to ``LoadImageW()``. Now it stays longer. The icon in the taskbar is the ``cmd`` icon. Correct, it is a console app so it just pops up a console window and the corresponding icon. Is ``LoadImageW()`` enough to set the class icon? Don't you need to set ``hIcon`` in ``WNDCLASSW``? I like cooperating with you; chatting might be better.

Comment: It works. I use winapi, and then you need the following: ``hIcon=LoadImageW( GetModuleHandleW(0 as LPCWSTR), MAKEINTRESOURCEW( 1 ), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, 0 ) as HICON;`` Could you add this to the answer? Many people will read and use it. Loading the image is not enough to change the *class icon*.

Comment: And don’t forget to encode your `RC` file as UCS2, otherwise it will come out with unexpected errors

Answer (score 2):

This text complements Answer 1 by [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable), adding information for the users of `winapi`.

Create the resource file `<name>.rc` and `build.rs` as described in Answer 1, and place these files along with the icon file `<name>.ico` in the project root directory. Add the build dependency to `embed-resource` in `Cargo.toml`. The application `exe` file built with these changes will embed the icon from the icon file.

To change the *class icon* that is shown in the taskbar, set the `hIcon` member in `WNDCLASSW` as follows:

```
hIcon = LoadImageW( 
    GetModuleHandleW(0 as LPCWSTR), // hInst; the .exe file
    MAKEINTRESOURCEW( 1 ),          // name; use the resource number in the .rc file
    IMAGE_ICON,                     // type
    0,                              // cx
    0,                              // cy
    0                               // fuLoad
    ) as HICON;
```

Comment: While I somehow forgot to follow up on [your request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75038925/how-to-link-an-icon-to-a-rust-windows-application/75046993#comment132427741_75039811), I'm curious as to whether the `fuLoad` value passed makes a difference. You're using `0` (aka `LR_DEFAULTCOLOR`) here. Does your code exhibit different behavior if you used `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` instead?

Comment: @IInspectable: this project is in stand by right now. It is about Rust, while I'm working with C++. But I'll check it upp and answer you.

Comment: @IInspectable: I've tested LoadImageW with the parameter fuLoad set to (in a sequence): LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS, LR_LOADTRANSPARENT, LR_MONOCHROME, LR_VGACOLOR. I could not see any change in the icon.